# Performance issue with Linq query - navigation properties to blame?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a Linq query that is taking far longer than its SQL equivalent (about 5-6 seconds for Linq, 50 ms for SQL). Obviously something is going wrong in the translation, I even have an idea what, but I don't know how to solve it. The query is below:

```
from data in DbContext.CoacheeData
group data by new { data.User.CompanyId, data.Date } into g
select new GroupedDayData
{
    Id = g.FirstOrDefault().User.CompanyId == null ? "none" : g.FirstOrDefault().User.CompanyId,
    Name = g.FirstOrDefault().User.Company.Name == null ? "none" : g.FirstOrDefault().User.Company.Name,
    Date = g.FirstOrDefault().Date,
    Steps = g.Sum(x => x.Steps),
    Distance = g.Sum(x => x.Distance),
    CaloriesBurned = g.Sum(x => x.CaloriesBurned),
    LightlyActiveMinutes = g.Sum(x => x.LightlyActiveMinutes),
    FairlyActiveMinutes = g.Sum(x => x.FairlyActiveMinutes),
    VeryActiveMinutes = g.Sum(x => x.VeryActiveMinutes),
};
```

I suspect the use of the navigation property User in my group by is causing a subquery to be executed for each record in CoacheeData. I can improve the efficiency by about 1.5 seconds by joining the user and company tables manually, like so:

```
from data in DbContext.CoacheeData
join user in DbContext.Users on data.UserId equals user.Id
join company in DbContext.Companies on user.CompanyId equals company.Id
group data by new { user.CompanyId, company.Name, data.Date } into g
select new GroupedDayData
{
    Id = g.FirstOrDefault().User.CompanyId == null ? "none" : g.FirstOrDefault().User.CompanyId,
    Name = g.FirstOrDefault().User.Company.Name == null ? "none" : g.FirstOrDefault().User.Company.Name,
    Date = g.FirstOrDefault().Date,
    Steps = g.Sum(x => x.Steps),
    Distance = g.Sum(x => x.Distance),
    CaloriesBurned = g.Sum(x => x.CaloriesBurned),
    LightlyActiveMinutes = g.Sum(x => x.LightlyActiveMinutes),
    FairlyActiveMinutes = g.Sum(x => x.FairlyActiveMinutes),
    VeryActiveMinutes = g.Sum(x => x.VeryActiveMinutes),
};
```

But my select still looks identical, perhaps the navigation properties there are causing similar issues? That seems strange though, since I've used navigatio properties in the select of Linq queries before without issue. In any case, I'm not sure if my suspicions are correct, and if they are, why it happens and how I can fix it.

Comment: There is no need for `g.FirstOrDefault()` because the select will only run when there is a collection returned by `groupby`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that expressions to get *CompanyId*, *CompanyName* and *Date* are too complex  and Linq To Sql is unable to translate this in proper Sql.

1) try to remove part that selects *CompanyId*, *CompanyName* and *Date* to see if it gets faster;

```
var result =
    from data in DbContext.CoacheeData
    join user in DbContext.Users on data.UserId equals user.Id
    join company in DbContext.Companies on user.CompanyId equals company.Id
    group data by new { CompanyId = user.CompanyId, CompanyName = company.Name, Date = data.Date } into g
    select new GroupedDayData
    {
        Steps = g.Sum(x => x.Steps),
        Distance = g.Sum(x => x.Distance),
        CaloriesBurned = g.Sum(x => x.CaloriesBurned),
        LightlyActiveMinutes = g.Sum(x => x.LightlyActiveMinutes),
        FairlyActiveMinutes = g.Sum(x => x.FairlyActiveMinutes),
        VeryActiveMinutes = g.Sum(x => x.VeryActiveMinutes),
    };
```

2) if it helps, replace your expression with something like `g.Key.CompanyId`, `g.Key.CompanyName` and `g.Key.Date`

```
var result =
    from data in DbContext.CoacheeData
    join user in DbContext.Users on data.UserId equals user.Id
    join company in DbContext.Companies on user.CompanyId equals company.Id
    group data by new { CompanyId = user.CompanyId, CompanyName = company.Name, Date = data.Date } into g
    select new GroupedDayData
    {
        Id = g.Key.CompanyId,
        Name = g.Key.CompanyName,
        Date = g.Key.Date,
        Steps = g.Sum(x => x.Steps),
        Distance = g.Sum(x => x.Distance),
        CaloriesBurned = g.Sum(x => x.CaloriesBurned),
        LightlyActiveMinutes = g.Sum(x => x.LightlyActiveMinutes),
        FairlyActiveMinutes = g.Sum(x => x.FairlyActiveMinutes),
        VeryActiveMinutes = g.Sum(x => x.VeryActiveMinutes),
    };
```

3) if this helps, add null check back and you should get the same result, but faster;

```
var result =
    from data in DbContext.CoacheeData
    join user in DbContext.Users on data.UserId equals user.Id
    join company in DbContext.Companies on user.CompanyId equals company.Id
    group data by new { CompanyId = user.CompanyId, CompanyName = company.Name, Date = data.Date } into g
    select new GroupedDayData
    {
        Id = g.Key.CompanyId ?? "None",
        Name = g.Key.CompanyName ?? "None",
        Date = g.Key.Date,
        Steps = g.Sum(x => x.Steps),
        Distance = g.Sum(x => x.Distance),
        CaloriesBurned = g.Sum(x => x.CaloriesBurned),
        LightlyActiveMinutes = g.Sum(x => x.LightlyActiveMinutes),
        FairlyActiveMinutes = g.Sum(x => x.FairlyActiveMinutes),
        VeryActiveMinutes = g.Sum(x => x.VeryActiveMinutes),
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Removing CompanyId and CompanyName indeed improved the performance drastically (bumped it down to about 250 ms, which is fine). However, replacing the FirstOrDefault() call by Key did not change the performance (still around 4 seconds), nor did the null check.

Comment: Could you please post SQL query that is being generated by LINQ? You can use SQL Server Profiler to extract the query.

Comment: Also, try to execute query without aliasing `GroupBy` key. ...
group data by new {user.CompanyId, company.Name, data.Date} into g
select new GroupedDayData
    {
         Id = g.Key.CompanyId,
         Name = g.Key.Name,
         Date = g.Key.Date,
         Steps = g.Sum(x => x.Steps),
...

Comment: Ah, makes sense now. When I read your initial answer I thought for sure that the use of `g.Key` instead of my `g.FirstOrDefault()` would be the solution, so I was a bit puzzled when it didn't. Turns out it was my fault: I still had a `FirstOrDefault` at my Date that I forgot to swap out. When I did that, performance improved to around 200ms again. So in short, your first answer was correct, and solves my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, missed Date field in my answer text. Updated my answer. Glad it helped!